# Philosophical responses to possible biases in the philosophical canon?

Tags: metaphilosophy

Philosophy is supposedly universal, but nearly all of the accepted western philosophical canon has been created by affluent white European men. Are there (canonical) philosophers who have directly interrogated how their own position in society (in relation to race, gender and privilege) affects the way they think and the conclusions they reach?  If so, who are they, and what conclusions have they reached?

Comment: Western philosophical tradition ...white European men. It seems unavoidable. Indian phil ... Asian men, and so on.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not asking about how the situation came about, the question asks whether any philosophers have addressed the problem of the limited perspective from which their philosophy is carried out.

Comment: See [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37584/please-explain-perspectivism-to-me) about Nietzsche's *perspectivism* : every philosophy/thinking is according to some perspective, and thus unavoidably limited.

Comment: See the title essay in Karl Popper's 'The Myth of the Framework'.

Comment: Both these comments sound like answers to me, would you mind expanding a little on what the authors you mention have to say, what actions they suggest might address the problem, and promoting your comments to answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an accusation and not a question.

Comment: @jobermark I recently heard about this very topic in a lecture and I think it is legitimate. Foucault talked about this, and others since then (Cornell West, Edward Said, and some Indian-American philosopher whose name I forgot)

Comment: @AlexanderSKing The heading question is good. But as laid out in detail in the post, this is so condescending it is basically an 'agree with me!' question. It needs a better 'clarity to criticism' ratio.  From Plato speaking through Socrates speaking through Diotima, this is a topic, but never a major one until this century.  We officially disapprove 'laundry list' questions.  So what is being asked for?

Comment: What have eastern academics to say about the fact that their philosophical teachings are mostly about oriental philosophers?They're readings are Kenko,Lao Tzu,Confucius,etc. Apply the same for other cultures.
There is no prejudice nor limited perspective. They worked on different problems.Western philosophers who work on problems addressed by eastern philosophers based their work on them.
To be honest, I find this question to be biased on its premise, and it looks like the type of question that a "social justice warrior" or "feminist" ask these days. Philosophy is about problems, not people.

Comment: @Cure Putting feminist in quotes is going too far.  Every modern philosophy has to handle the fact of social bias in some way.  Pointedly disrespecting people will not make them go away.  If philosophy is not about people, why do major schools almost all have the names of individual *people*?  Tell me anyone studies Nietzsche as a set of problems...

Comment: I agree with @jobermark . If you strip out the condescension and merely ask about what contemporary philosophers think about this, then it's a good and interesting question. As written, it seems more like an agenda with a question mark.

Comment: Could someone explain what it is they don't get about the question. Putting it on hold just places a generic "It's hard to tell what you're asking" note. The fact that there are two answers already indicates that it's perfectly clear what I'm asking. I'm not going to apologize for the tone, I'm sure some people take institutional racism, and gender bias in their stride, but personally it makes me sick. I've just read some of the excellent discussions linked by Chris Sunami in his answer. I'm clearly not alone in these concerns (which is exactly what I asked the question in order to check).

Comment: Whether or not racism is despicable does not matter for what the tone of your question should be. For me, it seems clear what is being asked, but I can imagine that some people stop reading when a question starts with "Are philosophers generally naive enough". I stopped there the first time. --- I see this has now been removed, so I'm reopening this.

Comment: The born of the nations and modern racism (because racism is a modern "idea") is a very interesting matter. Learn about it. Nations were created after the 16th century. @Isaacson It doesn't appear that it makes you sick enough as to sit down and learn about the history of the world. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism // From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism#History): Racism, thus defined, is a modern conception, for prior to the XVIth century there was virtually nothing in the life and thought of the West that can be described as racist.

Comment: @Isaacson You might find [this earlier question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10195/is-western-philosophy-inherently-patriarchal-and-mono-racial?rq=1), the answers, and [this article](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/comment/opinion/philosophy-is-deadwhite-and-dead-wrong/2012122.article) linked to it of interest.

Comment: @Chris Sunami It's disturbing to see that the previous question on this subject was also down voted and then closed. The new title is much closer to what I was trying to ask, thanks and the article very interesting. I'm glad that people are at least raising the issue in the media.

Comment: I edited again, since people still seemed to be distracted by extraneous material.

Comment: @Chris I'm losing track of all the edits, but it sounds fine as it is now, thanks for your efforts to keep the question alive.

Comment: Just for anyone coming to this question afresh, there is an interesting survey result here http://philpapers.org/surveys, demonstrating statistically significant biases in the conclusions modern philosophers draw on a range of issues based on their gender, age and country of affiliation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among recognized philosophers who have specifically addressed issues of race and gender in relationship to exclusion from the accepted intellectual canon, two of the best-known, best respected and most influential are (Afro-Caribbean) Marxist [Franz Fanon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frantz_Fanon), and feminist existentialist [Simone de Beauvoir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simone_de_Beauvoir).  Both of them took some inspiration from Hegel's concept of [The Other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other) as a necessary counterpart to the normalized self, a philosophical concept that has become foundational to theories of the systemic exclusion of minority voices from intellectual conversations.

For a very different reaction to some of the same basic issues, John Rawls' influential *[Justice as Fairness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_as_Fairness)* introduced the concept of a "veil of ignorance."  The idea is that we should constitute society as we would choose if we had no idea which person we would be in that society.  Behind the veil, you don't want anyone to be too poor, or too hopeless and you want everyone to have a fair shot, because once you leave the veil, you might well find yourself as one of the people on the bottom of your new system, not the top.

In today's globalized society, which necessitates a certain level of comfort with diversity, there is no dearth of thinkers to address the subject. There have also been [moves towards integrating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legitimacy_of_Chinese_philosophy) Asian figures such as Lao Tzu and Confucius into the canon, as well as greater visibility around the fact that there are traditional members of the Western canon, like [Saint Augustine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Hippo), who were not actually white Europeans, and that Islamic philosophers like [Averroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averroes) were instrumental in keeping the tradition of Greco-Roman philosophy alive during the European Middle Ages. It's additionally well worth noting that the current conception of a single unified "white European race" [considerably postdates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteness_studies) most of the canon. Accordingly, a cause of greater concern for many than the historical paucity of non-white-male figures in the philosophical canon is the fact that [disparities continue](http://read.hipporeads.com/why-i-left-academia-philosophys-homogeneity-needs-rethinking/) into the present day.  The [reasons](http://www.latimes.com/opinion/op-ed/la-oe-0306-schwitzgebel-cherry-philosophy-so-white-20160306-story.html) behind this remain obscure and controversial, as do the [proposed solutions](http://parablemania.ektopos.com/archives/2011/09/whitephil.html).

Comment: "... as great or greater as their European counterparts," - What does this mean?

Comment: Thanks for the links they are an interesting read. I've read Simone de Bouvoir, but have not heard of Franz Fanon, so I'm grateful for the suggestion. I was reluctant to ask this question because I knew the sort of response it would get. Questioning the way philosophy is done is not popular here, but having read your answer I'm glad I did. The rest of you can safely close this question now, hopefully if you shut your eyes it will go away.

Comment: The claim that Greco-Roman philosophy would be lost is wrong. Greek philosophy (specifically Aristotle) would have been missing over half of its text, but Roman texts survived.

Comment: For anyone who downvotes, I'd appreciate a comment explaining why.  This answer is sourced, objective, on topic and factual, and I've edited to respond to all concerns actually raised in the comments section.

Answer (score -1):

In its current form (9/22), you make a big assumption that seems deeply inaccurate when you state `It seems unlikely that only affluent white men have anything interesting or useful to say about life.` I don't know anyone who ascribes to that position. The argument is about whether all things that are "interesting or useful to say about life" are per ipse philosophy *OR* whether philosophy refers to a particular tradition that descends from Plato and considers these questions. And then whether similar traditions elsewhere should be included by extension or not.

Stated another way, no one faults biology for not being physics, and several people who oppose including other traditions in the definition of philosophy do so not because they think such things are uninteresting but because they don't think interesting = philosophy. (This seems to be for instance the position maintained by both Leiter and Tampio in their dissents from the need to include everything and anything interesting in philosophy).

Or to give a second analogy, is learning Danish philosophy? I find learning Danish to be very interesting and raise questions about how life works, but I don't for a second imagine that it should be a required part of any program.

There's been quite a lot of discussion about how white, dead, and male the canon is. But when I say discussion I mean I've seen it the most not as philosophical treatise but as question concerning the profession (i.e. teaching in universities, publishing in journals) than in actual books and publications..

1. Several recent discussions at the dailynous: http://dailynous.com/2016/03/10/teaching-and-the-philosophical-canon/
2. An argument about how/whether Chinese philosophy fits in the canon. I'm familiar with HUANG Yong having written a piece for the APA newsletter. Bryan van Norden and Jay L Garfield wrote something in the [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/11/opinion/if-philosophy-wont-diversify-lets-call-it-what-it-really-is.html?_r=2&pagewanted=all). [Tampio](https://aeon.co/ideas/not-all-things-wise-and-good-are-philosophy) (who I'd never heard of when I was at Fordham) defends the current balance in terms of teaching. Some responses: [Brian Leiter](http://leiterreports.typepad.com/blog/2016/05/anglophone-departments-arent-departments-of-european-and-american-philosophy.html) [Brian Leiter again](http://leiterreports.typepad.com/blog/2016/09/maybe-not-all-wise-and-interesting-work-is-philosophy.html). Twitter world: https://storify.com/BryanVanNorden/getting-started

It comes up very frequently on the warp weft way blog.

But in general it comes up from the side of people do areas of philosophy that feel excluded.

(I think there's similar stuff in African / African American philosophy, etc., but since I don't work in those areas I don't run into it -- (this in turn happens because there's a difference between getting/holding a job in philosophy and "doing philosophy." The former necessitates brand maintenance and publishing in sufficiently prestigious journals and presses; the latter does not. ))

I'll repeat because maybe it's not clear enough. I publish in Chinese and comparative philosophy inter alia, but I can at least see what is being debated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that about Confucius. Reference?

Comment: All nations are created after the 16th century

Comment: @ChrisSunami the first paragraph is now longer a part of the answer as it has been updated -- just as the question has been updated.

Comment: @JohnAm I don't actually grasp the feature in question that you believe would be improved by editing, but I also don't really care about rep / voting.

Comment: I think your answer is interesting, but your initial argument is disingenuous. Philosophy may be a specific field of study descended from Plato, but it is neither seen that way by the general public, nor does it act that way academically (questions about ethics for example are directed to philosophers, not to one philosopher, one native American shaman and a Buddhist just to get a range). Philosophy has to take responsibility for what it is is now, not what it started out as.

Comment: @Isaacson "shaman" and "Buddhist" are non-secular titles.

Comment: @JohnAm  So is 'Theology', yet it is right there in the tag list.

Comment: @Isaacson People routinely do direct ethical questions to professional Buddhists, and to the Christian clergy, who often use the traditional inclusion of theology in philosophy to answer from an equal footing.  So the comment is just more accusation and not a reflection of anyone's actual behavior.

Comment: @jobermark My point is that conventional philosophy is held in higher academic esteem than Native American dream stories, or afro-caribbean poets, for example, and yet the society it now exists in contains all these cultures. I'm obviously not trying to say that no-one ever asks Buddhists anything, but the academic esteem in which the different approaches are held is massively different.

Comment: @Isaacson I think it's less that the argument is disingenuous than that philosophy qua profession and academic discipline is not what many people who are not in academia think it is ... Whatever responsibilities "Philosophy" has, where would they come from? Does "Civil engineering" have responsibilities to make cheaper roads?

Comment: If your last comment is your point, then it's more an accusation about how academia works, then a question about philosophy. And again, you're doing this backwards, you're saying X is important, therefore it should be a part of philosophy. But there's no basis for that argument. If you believe only things taught in academic philosophy departments are important, that's your fallacious belief.

Comment: @Isaacson Yes, and that is true in math, too.  And physics.  But do we think that only white people do physics because the names on half of the objects are German?  Philosophy at least takes feminism, class analysis and culturally based political and ethical philosophies seriously as sets of thoughts.  What do physicists do about it?  See the problem?  What works, works, and even if someone Hindu or Arabic said the same stuff later rediscovered by Kant, we have already named Kantianism.  You can't undo erasure from history.

Comment: @ChrisSunami  Dead people are dead.  We can try to find the ones that were not successfully erased.  But no.  Gone is gone, and there is no problem with the statement.  However much remediation we manage, the damage is permanent.  Pretending otherwise is more racist/sexist/etc. than being clear on the issue.

Comment: @ChrisSunami It is less the intellectual equivalent of 'finders/keepers' than an acknowledgement that one's place in the canon is had by relationships, and not on one's own merit. Kant is Kant less because he is brilliant, and more because he came at the right time in the tradition and has shaped progress since then. I don't care if someone else actually had his ideas. i don't even really care if he actually existed. Knowing that would not change the history of the evolution of ideas anchored around his work.  That we  choose to lionize great men at all is a problem, not what race they are.

Comment: @virmaior You seem to be arguing two contrary positions, I wonder if you could elaborate. It seems on the one hand you're saying that philosophy is a very specific academic study (likening it to Biology), and then in a second argument saying that the esteem in which it is held is not relevant to it's social obligations because it is academia, not philosophy per se that is held in such esteem (i.e implying that philosophy is something other than its academic study).

Comment: @jobermark - That Physics is dominated by white affluent men is a problem from a social mobility point of view, but does not have any influence the body of Physics because their conclusions are verifiable by testing in the real world. The conclusions of philosophers, as the system currently works, are only verifiable (to the extent that any philosophical work is) by other accepted philosophers. The system is self-immunised and so the socio-political make up of the group "accepted philosophers" is uniquely important in a way that other scientific fields do not have to contend with.

Comment: Mostly I seem to be wasting time rather than "arguing two contrary positions" as you suppose. Basically, you don't seem to have a question about anything inside of philosophy. You seem to want a springboard to argue about something, which is not what the SE is designed for...

Comment: / Regarding your query which will be the last one I respond to, (1) "philosophy" is as I stated above both  (a) the name of an academic discipline that builds on Plato and has its own standards for publication etc and (b) a separate folk concept of "interesting thoughts about anything". You conflate these in your question and your comment. (2) Philosophy as an academic discipline, i.e. (1)(a). functions like other academic disciplines. I don't care about (1)(b). it is not a thing. it's an empty lay notion without coherence or activity of its own. It neither can nor can't include/exclude things

Comment: @jobermark - To clarify, Physicists only do the discovery, their results are tested by application to the real world. Philosophers as a group do both the discovery _and_ the testing of those discoveries by interrogation. Hence their position in academia carries a unique burden.

Comment: @virmaior - It was my understanding that the comments section is for the clarification of answers, your answer seemed to contain two contrary positions, I asked for clarification. That you don't like the conclusions I'm drawing has no bearing on whether my comments have any place in SE. No-one is forcing you write comments, if you feel you're wasting your time then by all means stop.

Comment: @Isaacson  Your answer displays a warped sense of objectivity and a problematic perspective on science.  This is something not suitable to address in a comment.  See Feyerabend or someone, or read other posts on science and objectivity here.

Comment: @jobermark Could you clarify to which answer you are referring, none of my comments mention objectivity. Also, if it's not something that can be addressed in a comment then perhaps refraining from comment might be a better strategy than just telling someone they're wrong and not explaining why.

Comment: @Isaacson The one starting with 'To Clarify' and the thing it supposedly qualifies.  The idea that Physicists have anything to discover -- something that is just there and is not personal and connected to the physicists themselves --  or that results can be applied to the real world -- which is just there and can be addressed clearly and directly -- are both assertions of objectivity.   I gave a reference you could use.  Along with explaining too much, complaining about finding out you are wrong is not a good use of comments.

Answer (score -1):

There is a substantial amount of material about creating knowledge in general in some recent writing with philosophical content. Creating knowledge requires generating variations on current knowledge and then selecting among them. The selection can take the form of adopting ideas. But you can also select ideas by refusing to provide material support to people advocating such ideas.

So the best way to ensure that disadvantaged people can affect philosophy is to allow them to critically discuss any idea they like, and to deny material support to people whose ideas they disagree with. Denying material support to academic philosophers is not really an option at the moment since they are funded by tax money. Universities get grants, many of them from the government, and put some of that money toward philosophy. You can't refuse to pay the taxes for this activity without being fined, going to prison and that sort of thing. So one way to make it possible for disadvantaged people to affect the philosophy is done would be to abolish all government funding of universities.

This is part of the more general insight that poor people benefit from free markets, not from government control of the economy. See "Capitalism" by George Reisman for more explanation.

Since philosophers are not advocating this, they have not done everything possible to allow disadvantaged people to correct them.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question asked by the OP.

Comment: I have changed the answer to say explicitly that philosophers have failed to do everything possible to take account of criticisms poor people might have of their ideas.

Comment: This still doesn't address the question, which asks for canonical responses, not your own personal solution.  If you are proposing George Reisman as an answer, you should make that more central and less of a sidenote.

Comment: It's bad practice to post a citation without explaining it. I posted the gist of the explanation and a place where you can find more details about the underlying ideas.